# What would be the domain of the function $\sqrt{\frac{\log_{0.2}(x-1)}{x^2-2x-8}}$?

Tags: functions, logarithms

I need to find the domain of the function

$$f(x)= \sqrt{\frac{\log_{0.2}(x-1)}{x^2-2x-8}}$$

Here's how far I could get:

So clearly for the square root to be real, whatever's inside has to be greater than or equal to 0.

$$\implies \frac{\log_{0.2}(x-1)}{x^2-2x-8} \geq 0$$

$$\implies \frac{\log_{0.2}(x-1)}{(x+2)(x-4)}\geq 0$$

Also, for the logarithm to exist, clearly $x>1$

But how do I proceed? Clearly for this to be greater than 0, both the numerator and the denominator must be of the same sign, i.e, either both have to be positive or both have to be negative. But how do I set those conditions?

Comment: We're good on noting that the denominator is negative on $(-2, 4)$ o/w positive, right? For the numerator, recall that $\log_b(x) = \log(x)/\log(b)$, and that $\log(x < 1) < 0$.

Comment: A useful tactic here is also to graph it, I've linked a desmos plot.

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6grjpbcmml

Comment: @TrostAft I got what you said about the denominator, but if $x<1$ the the logarithm itself wont exist on the reals right

Comment: I should clarify, for $x \in (0,1), \log(x) < 1$.

Comment: About the graph, could you tell me how to graph shifts if $x$ is replaced by $x-1$ in the logarithm graph? Then I can solve it myself

Comment: By mapping $x \mapsto x-1$, the 'graph' of $\log(x)$ shifts over by 1 to the right.

Comment: @TrostAft Ah thanks now I get the graphical method. However, it would be nice if you could help me with the algebraic approach too. I know how to apply the wavy-curve method but dont really know how to use it for loagrithms

Comment: Well, first the domain of $\log(x-1)$ is for $x > 1$, so that must be considered. So for $x \in (1,2), \log_{0.2}(x-1)$ is positive, but since for this $x$, the denominator is negative, this cannot be part of the domain. So $x > 2$. For this range $\log_{0.2}(x-1)$ is negative, thus if this is in the domain, $x^2-2x-8$ must also be negative. This only holds for $x \in (-2,4) \implies$ the domain is just $x \in (2,4)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just going by the properties of the logarithm and polynomials.

The denominator is negative for $x \in (-2,4)$ and positive elsewhere (ignoring critical points).

The numerator can be analyzed by noting that $\log_b(x) = \log(x)/\log(b)$. In our case $\log_{0.2}(x-1) = \log(x-1)/\log(0.2)$. Recall that $\log(x \in (0,1)) < 0$. Thus the numerator is defined for $x > 1$, positive for $x \in (1,2)$, and non-positive for $x \geq 2$.

Intersecting these two domains implies that we must have $x \in [2,4)$!

Comment: The desmos plot suggests that 2, 4 are both included in the domain? But clearly 4 cant be in the domain as that would make the denominator undefined

Comment: They are not part of the domain; that is just a function of desmos being unclear representing points infinitesimally close to $2$ and $4$.

Comment: @Techie5879 desmos doesnt show single point discontinuity. But if you try to locate that point it shows $(4, undefined)$

Comment: Alright, thanks, my book too states the answer to be [2,4]. Thats clearly wrong

Comment: That's me just being wrong, whoops! 2 definitely is.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, that really helped!!

Answer (score 1):

Edited answer:

$x=2$ is the critical point of the numerator, i.e., the point where the function changes it's value, whole those of the denominator are $x=-2,x=4$. Employing the [wavy curve method](https://brilliant.org/wiki/wavy-curve-method) for the denominator, we get that it is negative when $x\in (-2,4)$ and positive for $x\in (-\infty,-2)\cup(4,\infty)$. Also numerator is positive when $x\in (0,2)$, zero at $x=2$ and positive when $x\in (2,\infty)$. Now, it is easy to get that the domain is $x\in [2,4)$, using that $x>1$ for the logarithm to exist.

Hope that helps.

Comment: No, but from the graph and answer given in my book, the domain is stated to be $[2,4]$

Comment: belongs: ... $\in$ (is an element of)

Comment: @amWhy yes, pardon me. (Flustered face)

Comment: @Techie5879 yes that's correct, I have made a mistake and allow me to correct it.